# Is calling doLayout() method a must after adding child to a parent?

Tags: dynamic, extjs, panel, extjs4.1

In our application, there is a tabpanel in which we are adding/removing the panel dynamically.

The panels get added at the click of a menu item by the following code in menu handler:

```
Ext.getCmp('mainTabPanelId').add(getPanel());
```

Here `getPanel()` method returns the panel after creating it.

Assuming that the id of main tab panel is `mainTabPanelId` and that of the child panel is panelId, in this context, could someone guide at the following:

1. Is it necessary to call `doLayout()` on `mainTabPanel` after the add method?
2. Should the `doLayout()` be called on the `mainTabPane`l or on the newly added child panel, that is, `Ext.getCmp('mainTabId').doLayout()` or `Ext.getCmp('panelId').doLayout()`?
3. Will a call to `doLayout()` take care of all the issues related to rendering, like scrollbars esp.?
4. The method `getPanel()` should return an already created panel (using `Ext.create`) or should it return a config object (having `xtype:'panel'`)? Which one should be preferred for better performance keeping time in mind?

Answer (score 2):

[AbstractContainer::add()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.container.AbstractContainer-method-add)

> <...> If the Container was configured with a size-managing layout manager, the Container will recalculate its internal layout at this time too.

So you don't have to do **1** — **3** because:

[AbstractContainer::doLayout()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.container.AbstractContainer-method-doLayout)

> <...> The framework uses this internally to refresh layouts form most cases.

[AbstractContainer::defaults](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.container.AbstractContainer-cfg-defaults)

> For defaults to work, the child items must be added using {xtype: ......} NOT using Ext.create("widget.type",{}) © roger.spall

So I'd prefer return configuration object instead of components itself.

Comment: Thanks for the post o_nix. Unfortunately, if we don't call doLayout() then the layout looks broken but as soon as a call to doLayout() is made, then all the issues (like scrollbar appearing etc.) get fixed. We tested this in many browsers and found that doLayout() call is a must after a dynamic add.